# unable to get the title attribute from clicked event

Tags: jquery

I am not able to get the title attribute when that certain link is clicked, here is what I tried:

**this is the html:**

```
<li><a href="#" class="add_to_menu" title="Förderverein">+</a> test 1</li>
<li><a href="#" class="add_to_menu" title="Förderverein">+</a> test 2</li>
<li><a href="#" class="add_to_menu" title="Förderverein">+</a> test 3</li>
```

**thi is the jquery script:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.add_to_menu').click(function() {
        alert(this.attr("title"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `this` wrongly. You should wrap it as a jQuery object, i.e. `$(this)`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.add_to_menu').click(function() {
        alert($(this).attr("title"));
    });
});
```

Or, should you feel really inclined to use `this` as-is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.add_to_menu').click(function() {
        var this = $(this);
        alert(this.attr("title"));
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you that was the problem, I knew I was missing something, I am going to accept your answer in 12 minutes